# Access nested object with variable angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

```
obj {
  val1 {
    nestedval {}
  }
  val2 {
    nestedval {}
  }
}
```

I want to access nestedval and want val1 or val2 as a variable i am trying like

```
var getVal = obj.varible.nestedval
```

but some how it's not working for me can anyone please help me to achieve this using angularjs. Thanks for your valuable time Guys.

Comment: Not releated to angular. You example is not a valid JS object. Can you please update. Please add your error message.

Comment: There's an article in W3School explaining object creation: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: object structure I am trying to explain sorry if I missed any syntax error I am getting is Cannot read property 'nestedval' of undefined while when I try to print "variable" it's showing exact val which I am passing

Comment: Also I am saying in angular because I am not sure how to use variable in expression so

Comment: Thank you @dfsq for restructuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing that your object structure look like this (added `:` to make it valid):

```
obj = {
  val1: {
    nestedval: {}
  }
  val2: {
    nestedval: {}
  }
}
```

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to refer property by variable name:

```javascript
var variable = 'val2'
var getVal = obj[variable].nestedval
```